# Laravel belongsToThrough like relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

Now I have these methods:

Programme.php

```
public function institute()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Institute::class, 'institute_id')->withTrashed();
}
```

User.php

```
public function programmes()
{
    // These programmes belongs to the same institute
    return $this->belongsToMany(Programme::class);
}

public function getInstituteAttribute()
{
    return $this->programmes->first()->institute ?? null;
}
```

How can I fetch institute with one SQL query and keep the relationship?

Because now I fetch programmes into collection and then I fetch institute from DB and loose relationship along the way.

Would like something like:

```
public function institute()
{
    return $this->programmes()->first()->institute();
}
```

Comment: pour some more information

Comment: @MadhuNair here you go

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can eager load nested relationships, you can see more about them in [the the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

> To eager load nested relationships, you may use "dot" syntax:

```
User::with('programmes.institute')->find($id);
```

If you are trying to build a relationship between users and institutes you would want to do something like this:

```
public function institutes()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Institute::class, 'programmes', 'user_id', 'institute_id');
}
```

You can read here about the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#updating-belongs-to-relationships) for many to many relationships.

> In addition to customizing the name of the joining table, you may also
>   customize the column names of the keys on the table by passing
>   additional arguments to the belongsToMany method. The third argument
>   is the foreign key name of the model on which you are defining the
>   relationship, while the fourth argument is the foreign key name of the
>   model that you are joining to

Comment: Yea, but it isn't what I'm searching for :(

Comment: what are you searching for?

Comment: Would like to have a relationship

Comment: can you add your schema for the three tables to your question?

Answer (score 8):

### An inverted Has one through relationship will work.

If we have

> **Library -> Author -> Book**

like relationship then the following code will work (assuming **Author** table has **library_id** and **Book** table has **author_id** as foreign key)

```
public function library()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(Library::class,Author::class,
                                'id','id','author_id','library_id');
}
```